# mock createWriteStream jest unit testing

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, next.js, jestjs

how to make jest unit testing this file.ts and how to mock createWriteStream

```
import { join } from 'path';
import { createWriteStream } from 'fs';
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from 'uuid';

export async function saveUpload(file: any): Promise<string> {
  try {
    const filePath = join(
      __dirname,
      `../../src/uploads/${uuidV4()}-${file.filename}`
    );

    await file.createReadStream().pipe(createWriteStream(filePath));

    return filePath;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I need how to make file.spec.ts for testing this file with jest.js
this file is typescript file for saving uploaded file